# Angular drop down - Selected values at the top of multiselect dropdown

Tags: angular5, multi-select

I have a requirement to keep selected values at the top of dropdown list of a [multiselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown). I have kept selected values in one array (for each selected item), the original option list in another array, compared the index values and concatenated selected values to the top of array. Its working when i choose one value and not working for multiple values

**html**

```
<div>
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown  class ="ng-multiselect" [placeholder]="'Users'"
[data]="userList" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers"  [settings]="multiSelect"
name="user" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (click)="userSelectedAtTopOnClick()">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
onItemSelect(user: User) {
  this.userData = user;
}

userSelectedAtTopOnClick(): void {
    this.isUserDropDownWidgetHidden = document.querySelector('.dropdown-list').hasAttribute("hidden");
    if(this.isUserDropDownWidgetHidden ) {
      this.sortUserListAfterEachSelection(this.userData);
    }
}

sortUserListAfterEachSelection(user: User) {
    let arrPartner: Partner[];
    if(origInst) {
      const index = this.userList.findIndex(element => element.partnerId === user.partnerId);
      const item: Partner = this.userList[index];
      if (index > -1) {
        arrPartner = this.userList.splice(index, 1);
        arrPartner = arrPartner.concat(this.userList);
        this.userList = arrPartner;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Mishi, I did with lot of custom code. Unfortunately, I do not have that code as it is proprietary and doesn't remember as well as It is almost 2 years back post.